# python : cant open file 'hw.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

[here my output looks like, please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyEHd.png)as I m new in this programing world, I m trying to do some python code, but it seems like my raspberry pi doesn't recognise my folder 
here it looks like 
python : cant open file 'hw.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
my path and folder is existed, and I save the file by .py extension still it shows not found , please help me guys....

```
pi@raspberrypi :~/codes $ ls
hello hw.py 
pi@raspberrypi :~/codes $ python hw.py
python : cant open file 'hw.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

hw.py file contains:- 
print "hello world"

IT CLEARLY SHOWS MY FILE "HW.PY" IS IN THAT FOLDER, BUT STILL RASPBERRY PI DOESN'TRECOGNIZING IT ? HELP ME GUYS

Comment: are you sure it is `"hw.py"` and not `"hello hw.py"` ?

Comment: in console write `python h` and then press key `tab` and it should add rest of file name (if it can find file starting with `"h"`).

Comment: yeah I m opening "hw.py", not "hello"

Comment: What is the output of the command `ls -l`?

Comment: I mean - you try to open `hw.py` but maybe full name is `"hello hw.py"` and you need `python "hello hw.py"`

Comment: @abhijeet From the image you post, the real file name should be `"hw.py "` (a space at the end).  Try `python "hw.py "`.

Comment: why I add double quote ? while opening python code ? why should I space after py and before end double quote"

Comment: space at end it works... but why ? why we add double quote ?

Comment: You may accidentally added a space at the end of the filename when you saved the file.  Double quote or single quote should be used to specify the filename if there are spaces within the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you need to save the file in the same directory as your IDE.

Comment: yeah I save, by doing ls command it shows file in my working directory